# How can I write a query to extract recs with the same value in ColA but diff. values in ColB?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a query that will list only the records that have a matching value in Column A but their Column B value is not the same for that group.
I'm trying to extract all recs. like the example for Cola=2

```
ColA  ColB  Other Data
1     1234  xxxxx 
1     1234  xxxxx 
1     1234  xxxxx 
2     5678  xxxxx 
2     7531  xxxxx 
3     5555  xxxxx 
3     5555  xxxxx
```

I've tried several variations of this but I'm not having any success.

```
SELECT a.flnumb, a.fllt, a.flmcu, a.flobj, a.flsub, a.flapyc,     
       a.flaid, a.flco,                                           
       a.fllct, a.flctry, a.flfy, a.flupmj                        
FROM tablename a                                                    
WHERE a.FLNUMB IN(SELECT b.FLNUMB FROM tablename AS b) and          
      a.FLMCU <> b.FLMCU and                                      
      a.flctry = 20 and a.flfy = 16 and a.flobj in('1037','1337')
```

Comment: Are you familiar with self joins?

Comment: A little, but when I run that, I'm returning  too many rows.
ex. 
    select * from tablename a, tablename b  where (a.colA = b.colA and     a.colB <> b.colB) and ......additional where values for a.xxx

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to count the number of distinct `colB`s you have per `colA`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tablename
WHERE  colA IN (SELECT   colA
                FROM     tablename
                GROUP BY colA
                HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT colB) > 1)
```

Comment: this is still returning all records, in the table.  I only want those where ColA match but Colb are different among the matching Cola group.  (For each ColA Group, they should all have the same value in Colb).  I'm looking for those that do not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your self join.

```
select whatever
from yourTable a join yourTable b using (colA)
where a.colB <> b.colB
```

Some database engines support the keyword `using` and some don't.  You didn't specify yours.

Comment: This is for the IBM i V7R1